# Two different github accounts - Access problem

Tags: git, github

I have a github account with say a username 'abc'. If I create a repository in it and clone it on my system as

`git clone https://github.com/abc/demo.git` it gets cloned.

If I login into my another github account with username say 'xyz' and create a repository in it and if I try to clone the repository on my same system as

`git clone https://github.com/xyz/demo.git` it gives fatal error such as

```
Cloning into 'demo'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/instructor-git/demo.git/' not found
```

I am new to git and not able to diagnose the problem what wrong I am doing. Please help.

Comment: Check out this gist link out https://gist.github.com/rosswd/e1afd2b0b0d515517eac . If you simply modify this you will be bale to get the expected result .

Answer (score 1):

`/xyz/` in the url is not enough to tell which user is cloning. you need to be explicit about it: `xyz@`:

```
$ git clone https://xyz@github.com/xyz/demo.git
```

Comment: This is not working. I am using gitbash, does it has to do anything with the username used in it to login.

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions using ssh.
I faced the same problem and the only solution I found is:

1. to generate an access token with the right 'repo'
2. Use it in the clone url

   `git clone https://the_access_token@github.com/xyz/demo.git`